# How to target the N elements that are nested in another one?

Tags: html, css, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

My input is an `html` :

```html
<div class="grid--item user-info  user-hover">
   <div class="user-gravatar48">
      <a href="/users/22656/jon-skeet">
         <div class="gravatar-wrapper-48"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6d8ebb117e8d83d74ea95fbdd0f87e13?s=96&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="Jon Skeet's user avatar" width="48" height="48" class="bar-sm"></div>
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="user-details">
      <a href="/users/22656/jon-skeet">Jon Skeet</a>
      <span class="user-location">Reading, United Kingdom</span>
      <div class="-flair">
         <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score 1,440,518" dir="ltr">1.4m</span><span title="873 gold badges" aria-hidden="true"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">873</span></span><span class="v-visible-sr">873 gold badges</span><span title="9172 silver badges" aria-hidden="true"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">9172</span></span><span class="v-visible-sr">9172 silver badges</span><span title="9224 bronze badges" aria-hidden="true"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">9224</span></span><span class="v-visible-sr">9224 bronze badges</span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="user-tags">
      <a href="/questions/tagged/c%23">c#</a>, <a href="/questions/tagged/java">java</a>, <a href="/questions/tagged/.net">.net</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm interested at the first two `span` elements that are direct descendant of the `div` with the `class="user-details"`.

For that I'm using a css selector but this one returns 9 results rather than only two : [https://try.jsoup.org/~orgt_meWno3AxzO0GzxMBldEhIk](https://try.jsoup.org/%7Eorgt_meWno3AxzO0GzxMBldEhIk)

I tried an implementation in python but same problem :

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.select('div.user-details span:nth-child(-n+2)')

# [<span class="user-location">Reading, United Kingdom</span>,
#  <span class="reputation-score" dir="ltr" title="reputation score 1,440,518">1.4m</span>,
#  <span aria-hidden="true" title="873 gold badges"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">873</span></span>,
#  <span class="badge1"></span>,
#  <span class="badgecount">873</span>,
#  <span class="badge2"></span>,
#  <span class="badgecount">9172</span>,
#  <span class="badge3"></span>,
#  <span class="badgecount">9224</span>]
```

My expected output is this :

```py
# [<span class="user-location">Reading, United Kingdom</span>,
#  <span class="reputation-score" dir="ltr" title="reputation score 1,440,518">1.4m</span>]
```

Can you guys tell me what's wrong with my css selector and how to fix it ?

My question is more about css-selectors rather than finding an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s look at your HTML. I have reformatted it so we can see the structure of the relevant part:

```
<div class="user-details">

  <a href="/users/22656/jon-skeet">Jon Skeet</a>

  <span class="user-location">Reading, United Kingdom</span>

  <div class="-flair">
    <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score 1,440,518" dir="ltr">1.4m</span>
    <span title="873 gold badges" aria-hidden="true">
      <span class="badge1"></span>
      <span class="badgecount">873</span>
    </span>
    <span class="v-visible-sr">873 gold badges</span>
    <span title="9172 silver badges" aria-hidden="true">
      <span class="badge2"></span>
      <span class="badgecount">9172</span>
    </span>
    <span class="v-visible-sr">9172 silver badges</span>
    <span title="9224 bronze badges" aria-hidden="true">
      <span class="badge3"></span>
      <span class="badgecount">9224</span>
    </span>
    <span class="v-visible-sr">9224 bronze badges</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

You say that you are wanting to target the first two span descendants of `div.user-details`, which is `span.user-location` and `span.reputation-score`. (You haven’t said *why* you want to do this, which would have been helpful background information.)

The selector you are trying to use is `div.user-details span:nth-child(-n+2)`. The first part of the selector is okay: `div.user-details span` returns all span descendants of `div.user-details` (which number 14). By adding the `:nth-child(-n+2)` you are filtering the results to include only those spans which are the first or second *child of their parent* (which number 9). What you actually want to do is to filter the results to include only those spans which are the first or second *descendant of `div.user-details`*, but there is no `:nth-descendant()` pseudo-class which will allow you to do that. With the structure you have, I don’t understand why you want to do this anyway.

You will simply need to invent a different way to target your desired elements. Can’t you just use their class names?

```
.user-location, .reputation-score
```

My other comment is that you have a lot of spans inside that `flair` element. You could improve the semantics by using some list elements. This might make it easier to target the elements you want to target.